Camera-shy black and green damselfly in Taiwan - species identification?
These photos are from April 7 and 21, 2024 in northern Taiwan, taken in dark, moist forest locations about 10 meters apart, of a damselfly species I've never seen before, here or anywhere else. I suspect it might be the same individual.
Photos are blurry - it's difficult to sneak up on, and fiddling with my cellphone to try to focus better scares it away. Nonetheless, I can say the following:

The front part of the body (head and thorax) seems dark but iridescent green.
The long thin abdomen is very dark or black.
The wings appear black when folded (and to the eye when flying) but when I boost the brightness or look at screenshots from videos, the wings seem to be brown rather than black. I can't be sure if they are the same color on the top and botom surface either.
The wingtips contain a small bright white pterostigma. It seems most/all dragonflies and damsel flies have these counterweights. In Aviation SE see Why this inertial regulator of dragonfly wing pitch reduces self-excited coupled flapping and feathering vibrations and improves gliding flight speed



click for full size:
 
 
 
screenshots of short unsuccessful video attempts
 

Update:
I think that Arrow's answer has nailed it!
A few days later I hiked the same path again, and about 100 meters from the initial sighting I met two more individuals. This time they were out in the open and bolder, and between swatting mosquitos and fumbling with a telephone that's supposed to be a "camera" I eventually got some better photos.
I'll add them here as confirmation of @Arrow's identification.



It appears to be a female Ebony Jewelwing(Calopteryx maculata). Females, but not males, have the white pterostigma and "smoky bronze wings"; where females have dull brown-black abdomen, males have the beautiful, shiny blue-green color all over the body. Wing color darkens with age. The problem is their range doesn't include Taiwan. So, not posted as an answer. Might be a hybrid of C. japonica x orientalis? Or an invader...

@anongoodnurse wow Wow WOW! It's exciting either way. Sounds like the title of a movie someone should make "Invasion of the Damsel Flies" :-) Not an invader, but I also spotted this bird a few weeks ago. It's range does include Taiwan but the sightings seem much lower than for surrounding countries south and east. https://ebird.org/species/whrsha

This is a very tricky ID to confirm at first glance
The first photo is incredibly like that of an Ebony Jewelwing (Calopteryx maculata) however, Calopteryx maculata is native to the US and not found outside of the western world. A hybrid is extremely unlikely.
After further research, the range narrows the genus of this species to the genus Matrona. A genus of damselflies, native to Asia. This narrows it down to 8 species.
After concluding this, the white on the wings almost instantly confirms this as a Formosan Jewelwing (Matrona cyanoptera) The first photo looks so much like Calopteryx maculata because of the angle that the picture was taken at. When identifying species one should always assume the most likely, or mistakes are likely to be made. The chances of seeing a Calopteryx maculata thousands of miles away from it's range is not a good assumption to make
Congratulations on this beautiful find!

Image ref: https://www.inaturalist.org/photos/43422986, Photo 43422986, (c) nikaboli, all rights reserved

@uhoh Thanks so much for your positive feedback! I really appreciate it! I think you should improve your image quality to help others. Try using a macro lens if your phone has one. Or you can buy a macro attachment for your phone or a jewelry's loupe. This is a very beautiful damselfly and a good photo would be very rewarding. I wish you the best on your photographic endeavors ;)
